# Flask Celery update_state from inside another function

Tags: flask, celery, celery-task

I'd like to update the state of my Celery task from another function. Here's what I have now:

## The Route

```
@app.route('/my-long-function', methods=['POST'])
def my_long_function():

    param1 = request.form['param1']
    param2 = request.form['param2']

    task = outside_function.delay(param1, param2)

    return task.id
```

## Celery Task - starts some_python_script.handle in the background

```
@celery.task(name='outside_function')
def outside_function(param1, param2):
    with app.app_context():
        some_python_script.handle(param1, param2)
```

## some_python_script.handle:

```
def handle(param1, param2):
    param1 + param2
    # many, many different things
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to self.update_state the celery task so that I can easily request its status from my app, like so:

## some_python_script.handle (ideally):

```
def handle(param1, param2):
    param1 + param2
    # many, many different things
    self.outside_function.update_state('PROGRESS', meta = {'status':'progressing'})
```

## check progress (ideally):

```
@app.route('/status/<task_id>')
def taskstatus(task_id):
    task = outside_function.AsyncResult(task_id)
    response = {
    'state': task.state,
    'id': task.id,
    'status' : task.status,
    }

    return jsonify(response)
```

Or something similar. Would appreciate any help, I'm very new to Celery!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the task id for calling.
You can check [update_state](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.update_state).

The below code should work.

```
# capture id of celery task
ID = self.request.id

def handle(param1, param2):
    param1 + param2
    # many, many different things
    # update the state of celery task with direct reference to it
    self.update_state(task_id=ID, state='PROGRESS', meta = {'status':'progressing'})
```

Comment: It can't work because in the scope of `handle` there is no `self`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `bind=True` to the main celery task, you get access to the celery task object with the `self` keyword. Pass the task object to the next function using `self`.

```
@celery.task(name='outside_function', bind=True)
def outside_function(self, param1, param2):
    with app.app_context():
        some_python_script.handle(self,param1, param2)
```

The other function can accept this task object and update it:

```
def handle(celery_task, param1, param2):
    param1 + param2
    # many, many different things
    celery_task.update_state('PROGRESS', meta = {'status':'progressing'})
```

Answer (score 0):

use `celery_app.backend.store_result(task_id, state, result)` can fix this
`store_result` use by `update_state`